# Converting MP4 video via copy to an MKV to add subtitles from an results in jittery output

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-conversion

I am converting from MP4 to MKV to add subtitles.  Everything completes correctly but the results has a slight jitter.  When I run `ffprobe` the tbn (time base number) is different. I have tried everything I know to set the tbn but it usually changes the tbc instead.

Here is the command I am using:

```
ffmpeg -i file.mp4 -i file.srt -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -map 1 -c:v copy -c:a copy -c:s srt file.mkv
```

`ffprobe` on mp4:

```
Stream #0:0(und): Video: hevc (Main 10) (hev1 / 0x31766568), yuv420p10le(tv), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 2000 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 1200k tbn, 23.98 tbc (default)
```

`ffprobe` on mkv:

```
Stream #0:0: Video: hevc (Main 10), yuv420p10le(tv), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 1k tbn, 23.98 tbc (default)
```

This has worked for me before but the timescales on the source file may have been different. I don't really want to re-encode, I am just trying to copy from one container to another.

Comment: Odd. How long does this process take? Should be quite quick if you are doing a copy. Maybe try doing an MP4 to MP4 conversation to add the subtitles like this: `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i input.srt -c:v copy -c:a copy -c:s mov_text -metadata:s:s:0 language=eng output.mp4`

Comment: My player TV does not recognize subtitles in an mp4, only a mkv.  I know I can re-encode the mp4 with the subtitles hard coded into the video but I am trying to avoid that.

Comment: Well, the subtitles are not hardcoded when you use that command I provided. It is the same SRT files as if it were external, but just inside of an MP4 container. But when you say “My player TV” what do you mean? Do you mean a software TV player or a non-computer device you can play MKV items on? That might explain the issue better. If this is a device, please provide the make and model so we can assist you better.